# WHERE clause doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php

I've been trying to output the name of the students who have paid in partial.
I can output something when I doesn't use the 'WHERE' clause

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$partial = "Partial";
$full = "Full Payment";
$query = "SELECT student_name FROM student WHERE student.status ='".$partial."'";
$query .= "SELECT student_name FROM student ORDER BY student_name";
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
do {
    /* store first result set */
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
/* print your results */    
{
        printf("%s\n",$row[0]);
        printf("\n");
        printf("<br>");
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}   
} 
while(mysqli_more_results($link) && mysqli_next_result($link));
}
```

Sorry for the bad format of the question and for my bad english. Thank you and hoping for your responses

Comment: dont be sorry for the bad format, fix it

Comment: the 2 queries make no sense, why not just one?

Comment: Why do two queries? Pull the `status` with the name then do what you will with the partials.

Comment: No need for two queries, make it one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT student_name FROM student WHERE student.status ='".$partial."'";
$query .= "SELECT student_name FROM student ORDER BY student_name";
```

This code will result in `$query` being:

```
SELECT student_name FROM student WHERE student.status ='$partial'SELECT student_name FROM student ORDER BY student_name
```

As you are concatenating the two strings together without any separation.  You would need to add a separator `;` between the two queries.  However, why are you running two queries here?

Comment: I'm trying to output the names of students who have paid partially and after that query I would also like to output the names of all students. 

What do you mean by a ';' separator? The two queries already have a ';' to separate them. I'm really sorry I'm new here and I'm also a beginner in PHP

Comment: You're confusing PHP and SQL.  You have an ending `;` in PHP but not in your SQL query (inside the quotes).  Echo out $query so you can see...